# Symfony: how to set default subdomain in a group subdomains?

Tags: symfony

Symfony version: 3.0
I have set multiple sub-domains for my project:
`www.example.com`, `en.example.com` and so on.
for one article page the url is:
www.example.com/article-1.html
en.example.com/article-1.html

if i add a sub-domain for the current domain:
`article.www.example.com`, `article.en.example.com`
the `article.www.example.com` is not good solution, i want to remove the `www` sub domain is article.example.com, when user open the en.example.com, the article.en.example.com is working.
how to do it?

i don't want to make a route file for each language site.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on the main routing file in `/app/config` by adding an `host` field at the same level as your `path` field and `default` field. The host field should contain the domain and subdomain you want, like in this example :

```yaml
english_homepage:
    path:    /
    host:    article.example.com
    default: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:articles }

main_homepage:
    path:    /
    host:    www.example.com
    default: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage }
```

You can also use placeholder, parameters, and other possibilities.
With them, you should be able to create variable subdomains to fit your needs.

For more information, read this : [How to Match a Route Based on the Host](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html)